# window.open pop up window link in the new tab in all browsers

Tags: php, html

I have a html code, which opens google maps in the new pop up window - I would like to change to, that it will open in the new tab, could you please help me?

```
<a href="#" onclick="var popupWin = window.open(&quot;http://maps.google.com/;width=800,height=900,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,location=0&quot;);popupWin.focus(); return false;">View in Google Maps</a>
```

thank you

Comment: You can't control that.

Comment: why is that? I've tried target="_blank" - but does not work for me

Comment: @putvande Yes you can control that for some browsers.

Comment: Can you? Can you show how you can control if a window should be opened in a new tab or a window?

Comment: @MattK: It's an option in the browser.  A website cannot override/control that setting.

Comment: @putvande Yes... simply look at my answer which I suspect you down-voted as well. It will work for Firefox and Chrome which I've explained. Open up a Jsfiddle and try it out yourself, that's the best way to learn.

Comment: @bausinho: How does it "not work"?  What happened when you used `target="_blank"`?  Browsers (usually) have an option to set whether it opens a new window or tab.  JavaScript cannot control/change that setting.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I understand that it is a browser setting but you CAN control it in certain browsers if people don't mess with their default settings. Instead of blind unacceptance try it out for yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you use `target="_blank"` in FireFox and Chrome it will open a new tab. Other browsers will rely on their own preferences which you cannot control.

Update: After taking a closer look at your code it seems very confusing. Your syntax is incorrect. `window.open` uses the following syntax:

`window.open('URL', 'name', 'specs', 'replace');`

- Notice the commas (,) not semi-colons (;) to separate parameters.

You are also specifying the dimensions of the new tab, which doesn't make sense as the new tab specs would be the same as the current browser window.

Try the following if you wish to open up a new tab:

`<a href="http://maps.google.com/" target="_blank">View in Google Maps</a>`

Comment: Firefox has an option to set whether it opens in a new tab or window when you use `_blank`.  Chrome probably does too.

Comment: @RocketHazmat please try for yourself... here is my example [http://mattkeaveney.com/sandbox/window_test.html](http://mattkeaveney.com/sandbox/window_test.html)

Comment: It opened a new window.  Because I have that option changed in my Firefox.

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes as I noted in my other comment as long as you don't mess with your default settings for the regular web user clicking on a link will change the current window, and clicking on a link with target _blank set will open a new tab.

Comment: So you are still not able to control it with JS. It is browser behaviour. The user sets the behaviour, you can not override that with JS.

Comment: @putvande yes you can control it. If a user keeps their default settings (and if you believe some articles out there that say 95% of users don't change their default application settings), it IS possible to control whether a user opens a link in the current window, a new window, or in a new tab. Take a look at the sample link I provided in my comment above to try it out for yourself. If you have kept the default settings for the latest Firefox, Chrome, or even IE and Opera which I just tested a minute ago, it will work.